# Could I use these words: "堂嫣" rather than "唐嫣" for a girl's middle and given name?

Tags: traditional-characters

Could I use "堂嫣" rather than "唐嫣" as the middle and given name for baby girl ? Is it ok for use the word 堂 in the name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Update: I noticed that you are from Vietnam, so I searched about Vietnamese names and found out that you actually have middle names. However, unlike Vietnamese names, Chinese names usually only have two parts, 姓 and 名, and does not have a middle name in a strict sense.)

By “middle name”, I guess you mean 字辈, which has been used to suggest the generation someone belong to in a family traditionally. However, the use of 字辈 is less seen in modern names, and the two characters are mostly seen as whole.

As for 堂, it is totally okay to use it in a name. However, if you would like to use it as a 字辈, it would be better if you use the same 字辈 in her siblings' names.

Comment: Yes, I'm from Vietnam. So I would like to use "堂嫣" as a whole of "名" as you mentioned above. So I just wonder if the word "堂" can use to put in the name or not. So as you said "As for "堂" it is totally okay to use it in a name." that could make me confidence to use the word "堂" for choosing this word for my baby. Thank you!